# Passar imagem para outro form através do click do botão c# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, visual-studio

Estou fazendo um sistema de estacionamento, em que surgiu a necessidade de quando o usuário se cadastrar, no form principal apareça a um icone de um carro em cima da vaga dele (que é uma label), ou seja, ao ele clicar no botão 'cadastrar-se' no outro form, o form principal tem que aparecer um icone de carro em cima da vaga dele!

eu tentei da seguinte forma, no click do botao do form de cadastro eu instanciei um construtor do form principal, e no construtor do form principal, eu passei a imagem que deveria ir para a label, porem nao deu certo!

//Click do botão cadastrar, do form cadastro, primeiro eu crio o objeto depois instancio o form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cadastro cadObj = new Cadastro(Convert.ToString(horas), txt_placa.Text, txt_cor.Text, txt_modelo.Text);

        var formulario1 = new Form1(Properties.Resources.vermelho);


        btn_registrar.Enabled = false;

    }
```

//Construtor do form principal que é chamado no click do botão cadastrar

```
 public Form1(System.Drawing.Image imagem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        box15.Image = imagem;
    }
```

Eu só preciso que quando eu clicar em cadastrar o icone de um carro vá para a label, para referenciar que tem alguem ja ali na vaga!

Comment: Por que não deu certo?

Comment: tambem nao sei, acredito que talvez por que eu esteja instanciando um novo objeto e na verdade eu tenho que fazer isso no objeto atual que é criado quando o form abre
enfim.. nao tenho certeza, mas ja mudei minha ideia, dar um jeito de fazer tudo em um form só, trabalhar com forms no visual studio é um cu!!!

Comment: Tá, ainda não deu pra entender qual é o problema. "Não deu certo" é muito abstrato, precisamos saber o que ocorre, qual o comportamento esperado e qual o problema. Sobre sua última frase, é só porque você não está sabendo trabalhar, isso é tudo muito simples.

Comment: era esperado que o label que está no outro form(principal), recebesse o parametro(foto) passado ao clicar no botão para cadastrar, e que ao ele receber o parametro que esse label atribuísse essa foto para sua área delimitada, porem quando eu faço isso, nao acontece nada, nao da erro, e também nao funciona! nao sei se consegui esclarecer meu problema, mas espero que sim!

Comment: "*porem quando eu faço isso, nao acontece nada*" -> Com isso você quer dizer que o form não abre? Ou que ele não mostra o ícone como você quer?

Answer (score 0):

Falta seu código realizar a chamada do form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cadastro cadObj = new Cadastro(Convert.ToString(horas), txt_placa.Text, txt_cor.Text, txt_modelo.Text);

    var formulario1 = new Form1(Properties.Resources.vermelho);
    //chama o form com a imagem
    formulario1.ShowDialog();
    btn_registrar.Enabled = false;

}
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico? Deveria estar onde?

Comment: melhorei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso.
No form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Cadastro cadObj = new Cadastro(Convert.ToString(horas), txt_placa.Text, txt_cor.Text, txt_modelo.Text);
        cadObj.showDialog();

        //caso a imagem esteja vindo do form cadastro
        this.box15.Image = cadObj.imagem;

        //ou
        this.box15.Image = Properties.Resources.vermelho;

        btn_registrar.Enabled = false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Verifique se a função `button1_Click` está realmente sendo chamada.
- Faça breakpoints no seu código para debugá-lo, somente assim você encontrará o erro. Uma ajuda é utilizar o atalho F11 para debugar o código linha a linha, a partir do breakpoint. (faça um breakpoint e teste a função `button1_Click`.
- Como sua função `button1_Click` também é um Listener (neste caso, para o evento de click), verifique se realmente a escuta foi adicionada no evento de Click no arquivo de designer do formulário ao qual ele pertence. Algo como:

  this.Click += button1_Click;